# WSO2 EMM Server does not show content of Available Features pane

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I was trying to configure a WSO2 EMM server for iOS MDM.

After runing `mvn clearn install` through `carbon-device-mgt`, `carbon-device-mgt-plugins` and `product-emm`, extracting the built zip file and lauching the `bin/wso2server.sh`, I could log in the through `https://LOCAL_IP:9443/` with default admin password.

The problem was that to install the iOS MDM feature, I need to use the mentioned web control panel to add the feature. But as I followed the documentation as in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Installing+WSO2+EMM+iOS+Features+via+the+P2+Repository), I got a totally blank box in the `Add Feature` pane  demostrated in the picture of Step 3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems that I have an empty list of repositories right after installation. After adding a remote repository in 'http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/4.2.0/', it works as documented.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the add features option you need to add a repository 1st. please you the right most tab and add the repository which contains the feature you wish to continue.